# Get all the data from model of searched tag on another page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Simple Question and Answer Web App and I implement a feature of search tags and it will show all the questions associated with it.

And Now I am trying to show all the data of models in other page which is attached with that searched tag.

Then I make a query of another model with `searched tag` but it is showing.

> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'first_post'.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quest = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')

    objs = ''

    if query:
        objs = Question.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=query)

        answer = Answer.objects.filter(quest=query)

    context = {'objs': objs,}
```

When i run this then it is showing `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'first_post'`.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to make a page of search and if i search a tag then a link of another page of all the answers of the searched tags, But i have no idea how can i attach two views so one page can show results ( questions ) and another can show answers.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify which field you are looking for in quest table, it will look for id by **[default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)**. Therefore, you need to explicitly define the table name:

```
answer = Answer.objects.filter(quest__tags__name__icontains=query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer BUT How can i show the `Answer results` in different page ? I mean when I search a tag like `django` then questions will be displayed as results and a link of another page ( Answers ) will be there and all the answers associated with the tags shows there.

Comment: You can write a new view function and pass query as a parameter. Then filter `Answer` objects by that query and return the result. You also need to update [`urls.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher).

Comment: It would be better to open a new thread and include views, templates, urls files, so we can know what we are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, you need to filter answers against questions associated with the given tag:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')

    answer = ''
    objs = ''

    if query:
        objs = Question.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=query)

        answer = Answer.objects.filter(quest__in=objs)

    context = {'objs': objs,'answer':answer}

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```